# Reducing code when creating prior year test score in opposite subject

Tags: stata

I have some data that looks like this and the variable that I'm trying to create is `Math_score`:

```
Year     ID    Subject    Score    Math_score    
2011      1       m          30         30
2011      1       r          40         30
2012      2       m          50         50
2012      2       r          60         50
```

My colleague and I have come up with the following way of doing this:

```
bys id year: egen math = mode(score) if subject=="m"
by id year: egen math_score = max(math)
```

Or:

```
bys id year: gen math_score = score[_n-1]
replace math_score = math_score[_n+1] if math_score==.
```

Ultimately this is going to be used in a lagged variable to denote the prior year test score in the subject and in the opposite subject. We're sure there's a more elegant way of doing this with less code but we can't seem to think of one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier to do this in one:

```
clear 
input Year     ID    str1 Subject    Score    
2011      1       m          30        
2011      1       r          40        
2012      2       m          50        
2012      2       r          60        
end 
egen Math_Score = mean(Score / (Subject == "m")), by(ID Year)
```

Documented [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055).

We're dividing by a true-or-false expression evaluated as 0 or 1. If the result is 1, `Score` is used as is. If the result is 0, the result is missing and just ignored, which is precisely what you want here.

That said, you may be much better off with a different data structure:

```
 clear 
 input Year     ID    str1 Subject    Score    
    2011      1       m          30        
    2011      1       r          40        
    2012      2       m          50        
    2012      2       r          60        
 end 
 reshape wide Score, i(ID Year) j(Subject) string 
 list, sepby(ID) 

     +-----------------------------+
     | Year   ID   Scorem   Scorer |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. | 2011    1       30       40 |
     |-----------------------------|
  2. | 2012    2       50       60 |
     +-----------------------------+
```